# Delete entry from file

Tags: python, string, file

I have txt file with following data:

```
3455155, 117465776, 29972373, 27226577, 64735238
```

I need to delete an entry from this file, for example: `3455155`

I`m trying following:

```
def remove_entry_from_file(entry_id):
    f = open(file.txt, 'w+')
    data = f.read()
    new_data = re.sub(entry_id + '[, ]*', '' ,data)
    f.write(new_data)
    f.close()
```

As a result - file will be totally cleared. Where I`m wrong?

Comment: I`ve changed mode from w+ to r+ and new_data become non-empty and correct. But I`ve received following error while f.write: "IOError: [Errno 0] Error"

Comment: It is work for me, can you again past your updated code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you open with `w+`, the file will be emptied.

Instead, use `r+`. if you do so, you'll have to rewind your file before writing and maybe truncate it afterwards.

```
def remove_entry_from_file(entry_id):
    f = open(file.txt, 'r+')
    data = f.read()
    new_data = re.sub(entry_id + '[, ]*', '' ,data)
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(new_data)
    f.truncate()
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is when you open the file in `w` it is automatically truncated, so you are not reading anything:

```
burhan@sandbox:~/t$ cat foo.txt
0
aaaa
bbbb
cddd
dddddddd

Long sentence here which is not even read completely

The rest is ignored...
burhan@sandbox:~/t$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 16:53:07)
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f = open('foo.txt', 'w+')
>>> f.read()
''
```

You probably want to open the file in append mode `'a'`; or open the file for reading, close the file, and then open the file for writing and write the new line.

Opening it for writing will clear the contents of the file.

Answer (score 1):

An other solution would be to open the file twice, once to read data, once to write:

```
def remove_entry_from_file(entry_id):
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()

    new_data = re.sub(entry_id + '[, ]*', '' ,data)

    with open('file.txt', 'w+') as f:
        f.write(new_data)
```

Here, the [context managers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) (code blocks after `with ... as ...:`) take care of closing the file for you.